# purpose of grep "*" and $mfile/*

Tags: linux, unix, grep

What is the purpose of the first line and the 4th line?

```
 grep "*" /tmp/dirip.$$  
 if [ $? -eq 1 ]  #grep command returns 1 if no output found
 then
    mfile=$mfile/* 
 fi
```

Comment: Please, choose a **single problem**. Currently, you have two independent questions.

Comment: I wanted to know why is the asterisk between double quotes? Does the grep command search for an asterisk character or does the asterisk sign stand for repetition? Sorry it's my first bash project. I am very new to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The * is between quotes so the shell doesn't treat it as a special
character and do file glob expansion on it.  Since grep isn't told
to use an extended regular expression, it defaults (if it conforms to POSIX) to a basic
regular expression (BRE).  In a BRE, a * is not special when
it is the first character of the regular expression, as it is here.
So the pattern just looks for a line containing a * character.
The effect then of the first line is to write to stdout each line
in /tmp/dirip.$$ that has a * in it.  The purpose of the first line
is harder to discern.